# using TPL ActionBlock, Can I add a new item after the job completed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am using TPL `ActionBlock` in my application to implement parallelism.

I have an application that will perform an action based on user input. Sometimes the action takes more time and sometimes not, based on the input.

So the real purpose of the `ActionBlock` is that whenever an input came I want to show it in the UI first (having a window), then in the background perform the action. So the idea is like whatever comes from the user, show it in the UI and perform things parallely in the background.

Now, in the UI(window) I have a stop button to stop the user input. Whenever I click this function, the user will not be able to input anything more. And now I am calling `ActionBlock.Complete` method as well to check the Queue/Block is completed or not.

So here my doubt is,

I am calling `ActionBlock.Complete()` as a separate method based on the stop button click, which will wait for the job to complete then do some work and close the UI. Is this really a good idea or I have to call the `ActionBlock.Complete()` inside the constructor or where the `ActionBlock` is defined.

```
public void CheckJobQ()
{
    _jobs.Complete();
    _jobs.Completion.Wait();
}
```

and `_jobs` is the `ActionBlock`:

```
var executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100
};
_jobs = new ActionBlock<Tuple<Action<Element>, Element>>((job) =>
{
    job.Item1.Invoke(job.Item2);
}, executionDataflowBlockOptions);
```

Comment: _"Signals to the dataflow block **that it shouldn't accept or produce any more messages** and shouldn't consume any more postponed messages."_ - [`ActionBlock<TInput>.Complete()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1.complete?view=netcore-3.1) - Why do you think it is an option to complete it in the ctor?

Comment: Also: how does the question text match the title? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Have one more doubt here, if my ActionBlock is complete after calling_jobs.completion.Wait(), how I will start a new ActionBlock one more time. Is that possible or not.

Comment: When the State machine is in its final state ("completed") it cannot be reset, afaik. You need to create a new instance.

Answer (score -2):

All dataflow blocks are thread-safe, so calling:

```
_jobs.Complete();
```

...from the action of an `ActionBlock` is permitted and totally fine.

On the other hand the dataflow blocks are not deadlock-safe. So if you wait for the completion of the block while processing an element:

```
_jobs.Completion.Wait();
```

...you have probably shot yourself in the foot. The action will never be completed, and neither will the block itself.

Comment: yeah  i wouldn't use the term 'deadlock-safe' that doesnt exist (i get what you mean tho)